AMCL localization transform stability issues
Bug report
Required Info:

Operating System:

Ubuntu 22.04


ROS2 Version:

Humble binaries


Version or commit hash:

ros-humble-navigation2  1.1.14-1jammy.20240518.064247


DDS implementation:

Fast-RTPS, I've also tried CycloneDDS



Steps to reproduce issue
After starting a gazebo simulation with the robot state publishers, where 2 turtlebots are spawned, I start my modified nav2 bingup as follows:
ros2 launch turtleQ_nav bringup_with_ns_launch.py namespace:=tb0 use_namespace:=True  use_composition:=False slam:=True
This runs wiht no issues. The turtlebot's map can be viewed in rviz with no issues, and all the transforms are fine.
Then I launch nav2 and amcl for the second turtelbot with this command:
ros2 launch turtleQ_nav bringup_with_ns_launch.py namespace:=tb1 use_namespace:=True  use_composition:=False leader_namespace:=tb0 slam:=False
This starts up nav2 and amcl and reroutes the first turtlebots map to the second turtlebot (in /tb1/ namespace) and does localization with this map. I then set the initial pose manually so that AMCL can calculate a pose, but the transform tree gets messed up most of the time.
Here is my main modified nav2 bringup. The other launch files are left mainly unaltered, I can post them too if it is suspected to be important to resolving this issue.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import (DeclareLaunchArgument, GroupAction,
                            IncludeLaunchDescription, SetEnvironmentVariable)
from launch.conditions import IfCondition
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, PythonExpression
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.actions import PushRosNamespace
from launch_ros.descriptions import ParameterFile
from nav2_common.launch import RewrittenYaml, ReplaceString


def generate_launch_description():
    # Get the launch directory
    bringup_dir = get_package_share_directory('turtleQ_nav')
    launch_dir = os.path.join(bringup_dir, 'launch')

    # Create the launch configuration variables
    namespace = LaunchConfiguration('namespace')
    use_namespace = LaunchConfiguration('use_namespace')
    leader_namespace = LaunchConfiguration('leader_namespace')
    slam = LaunchConfiguration('slam')
    map_yaml_file = LaunchConfiguration('map')
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')
    params_file = LaunchConfiguration('params_file')
    autostart = LaunchConfiguration('autostart')
    use_composition = LaunchConfiguration('use_composition')
    use_respawn = LaunchConfiguration('use_respawn')
    log_level = LaunchConfiguration('log_level')

    # Map fully qualified names to relative ones so the node's namespace can be prepended.
    # In case of the transforms (tf), currently, there doesn't seem to be a better alternative
    # https://github.com/ros/geometry2/issues/32
    # https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/pull/30
    # TODO(orduno) Substitute with `PushNodeRemapping`
    #              https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/issues/56
    remappings = [('/tf', 'tf'),
                  ('/tf_static', 'tf_static')]

    # Create our own temporary YAML files that include substitutions
    bt_xml_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('turtleQ_nav'), 'behavior_trees', 'follow_point.xml')
    print("Behavior Tree XML Path: ", bt_xml_path)
    param_substitutions = {
        'use_sim_time': use_sim_time,
        'yaml_filename': map_yaml_file,

 }
    
    # Only it applys when `use_namespace` is True.
    # '<robot_namespace>' keyword shall be replaced by 'namespace' launch argument
    # in config file 'nav2_multirobot_params.yaml' as a default & example.
    # User defined config file should contain '<robot_namespace>' keyword for the replacements.
    params_file = ReplaceString(
        source_file=params_file,
        replacements={'<robot_namespace>': ('/', namespace),'<default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml>': bt_xml_path,
                      '<default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml>': bt_xml_path, '<turtlebot-namespace>': namespace},
        condition=IfCondition(use_namespace))

    configured_params = ParameterFile(
        RewrittenYaml(
            source_file=params_file,
            root_key=namespace,
            param_rewrites=param_substitutions,
            convert_types=True),
        allow_substs=True)

    stdout_linebuf_envvar = SetEnvironmentVariable(
        'RCUTILS_LOGGING_BUFFERED_STREAM', '1')

    declare_namespace_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'namespace',
        default_value='',
        description='Top-level namespace')

    declare_use_namespace_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'use_namespace',
        default_value='false',
        description='Whether to apply a namespace to the navigation stack')
    declare_leader_namespace_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'leader_namespace',
        default_value="",
        description='Namespace of the leader turtlebot that is transmitting map'
    )
    declare_slam_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'slam',
        default_value='False',
        description='Whether run a SLAM')

    declare_map_yaml_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'map',
        default_value="",
        description='Full path to map yaml file to load')

    declare_use_sim_time_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'use_sim_time',
        default_value='false',
        description='Use simulation (Gazebo) clock if true')

    declare_params_file_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'params_file',
        default_value=os.path.join(bringup_dir, 'params', 'nav2_params.yaml'),
        description='Full path to the ROS2 parameters file to use for all launched nodes')

    declare_autostart_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'autostart', default_value='true',
        description='Automatically startup the nav2 stack')

    declare_use_composition_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'use_composition', default_value='True',
        description='Whether to use composed bringup')

    declare_use_respawn_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'use_respawn', default_value='False',
        description='Whether to respawn if a node crashes. Applied when composition is disabled.')

    declare_log_level_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'log_level', default_value='info',
        description='log level')

    # Specify the actions
    bringup_cmd_group = GroupAction([
        PushRosNamespace(
            condition=IfCondition(use_namespace),
            namespace=namespace),

        Node(
            condition=IfCondition(use_composition),
            name='nav2_container',
            package='rclcpp_components',
            executable='component_container_isolated',
            parameters=[configured_params, {'autostart': autostart}],
            arguments=['--ros-args', '--log-level', log_level],
            remappings=remappings,
            output='screen'),

        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('turtleQ_slam'),'launch', 'online_async_with_ns_launch.py')),
            condition=IfCondition(slam),
            launch_arguments={'namespace': namespace,
                              'use_sim_time': use_sim_time,
                              'autostart': autostart,
                              'use_respawn': use_respawn,
                              'params_file': params_file}.items()),

        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(os.path.join(launch_dir,
                                                       'localization_with_ns_launch.py')),
            condition=IfCondition(PythonExpression(['not ', slam])),
            launch_arguments={'namespace': namespace,
                              'map': map_yaml_file,
                              'use_sim_time': use_sim_time,
                              'autostart': autostart,
                              'params_file': params_file,
                              'use_composition': use_composition,
                              'use_respawn': use_respawn,
                              'leader_namespace': leader_namespace,
                              'container_name': 'nav2_container'}.items()),

        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(os.path.join(launch_dir, 'navigation_launch.py')),
            launch_arguments={'namespace': namespace,
                              'use_sim_time': use_sim_time,
                              'autostart': autostart,
                              'params_file': params_file,
                              'use_composition': use_composition,
                              'use_respawn': use_respawn,
                              'container_name': 'nav2_container'}.items()),
    ])

    # Create the launch description and populate
    ld = LaunchDescription()

    # Set environment variables
    ld.add_action(stdout_linebuf_envvar)
    
    # Declare the launch options
    ld.add_action(declare_namespace_cmd)
    ld.add_action(declare_use_namespace_cmd)
    ld.add_action(declare_leader_namespace_cmd)
    ld.add_action(declare_slam_cmd)
    ld.add_action(declare_map_yaml_cmd)
    ld.add_action(declare_use_sim_time_cmd)
    ld.add_action(declare_params_file_cmd)
    ld.add_action(declare_autostart_cmd)
    ld.add_action(declare_use_composition_cmd)
    ld.add_action(declare_use_respawn_cmd)
    ld.add_action(declare_log_level_cmd)

    # Add the actions to launch all of the navigation nodes
    ld.add_action(bringup_cmd_group)

    return ld```

Also, here are my amcl params: 
```amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.2
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_footprint"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 100.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::DifferentialMotionModel"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.2
    update_min_d: 0.25
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05
    scan_topic: scan

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /<turtlebot-namespace>/odom
    bt_loop_duration: 10
    default_server_timeout: 20
    default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml: <default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml>
    default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml: <default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml>
    # 'default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml' and 'default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml' are use defaults:
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_to_pose_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # They can be set here or via a RewrittenYaml remap from a parent launch file to Nav2.
    plugin_lib_names:
      - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_smooth_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
      - nav2_assisted_teleop_action_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_bt_node
      - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
      - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_globally_updated_goal_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_is_path_valid_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
      - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_local_action_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
      - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
      - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
      - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
      - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_path_expiring_timer_condition
      - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
      - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_path_longer_on_approach_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_assisted_teleop_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_charging_condition_bt_node

bt_navigator_navigate_through_poses_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    failure_tolerance: 0.3
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugins: ["general_goal_checker"] # "precise_goal_checker"
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    # Progress checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    # Goal checker parameters
    #precise_goal_checker:
    #  plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
    #  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    #  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    #  stateful: True
    general_goal_checker:
      stateful: True
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    # DWB parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: 0.0
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 0.26
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_theta: 1.0
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 0.26
      min_speed_theta: 0.0
      # Add high threshold velocity for turtlebot 3 issue.
      # https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/issues/75
      acc_lim_x: 2.5
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 3.2
      decel_lim_x: -2.5
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -3.2
      vx_samples: 20
      vy_samples: 5
      vtheta_samples: 20
      sim_time: 1.7
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      transform_tolerance: 0.2
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"]
      BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      rolling_window: true
      width: 3
      height: 3
      resolution: 0.05
      robot_radius: 0.22
      plugins: ["obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: "scan dynamic_obstacles"
        scan:
          topic: /<turtlebot-namespace>/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
        dynamic_obstacles:
          topic: /local_obstacle_topic  # Topic name for local obstacles
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "PointCloud2"
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      robot_radius: 0.22
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /<turtlebot-namespace>/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      always_send_full_costmap: True

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    # Overridden in launch by the "map" launch configuration or provided default value.
    # To use in yaml, remove the default "map" value in the tb3_simulation_launch.py file & provide full path to map below.
    yaml_filename: ""

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    save_map_timeout: 5.0
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    use_sim_time: True
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
      tolerance: 0.5
      use_astar: false
      allow_unknown: true

smoother_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    smoother_plugins: ["simple_smoother"]
    simple_smoother:
      plugin: "nav2_smoother::SimpleSmoother"
      tolerance: 1.0e-10
      max_its: 1000
      do_refinement: True

behavior_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    behavior_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "drive_on_heading", "assisted_teleop", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/BackUp"
    drive_on_heading:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/DriveOnHeading"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Wait"
    assisted_teleop:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/AssistedTeleop"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_tolerance: 0.1
    use_sim_time: true
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    loop_rate: 20
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200

velocity_smoother:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    smoothing_frequency: 20.0
    scale_velocities: False
    feedback: "OPEN_LOOP"
    max_velocity: [0.26, 0.0, 1.0]
    min_velocity: [-0.26, 0.0, -1.0]
    max_accel: [2.5, 0.0, 3.2]
    max_decel: [-2.5, 0.0, -3.2]
    odom_topic: "odom"
    odom_duration: 0.1
    deadband_velocity: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    velocity_timeout: 1.0

And here are my slam_toolbox params:
  ros__parameters:

    # Plugin params
    solver_plugin: solver_plugins::CeresSolver
    ceres_linear_solver: SPARSE_NORMAL_CHOLESKY
    ceres_preconditioner: SCHUR_JACOBI
    ceres_trust_strategy: LEVENBERG_MARQUARDT
    ceres_dogleg_type: TRADITIONAL_DOGLEG
    ceres_loss_function: None

    # ROS Parameters
    odom_frame: odom
    map_frame: map
    base_frame: base_footprint
    scan_topic: /scan
    use_map_saver: true
    mode: mapping #localization

    # if you'd like to immediately start continuing a map at a given pose
    # or at the dock, but they are mutually exclusive, if pose is given
    # will use pose
    #map_file_name: test_steve
    # map_start_pose: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    #map_start_at_dock: true

    debug_logging: false
    throttle_scans: 1
    transform_publish_period: 0.02 #if 0 never publishes odometry
    map_update_interval: 5.0
    resolution: 0.05
    max_laser_range: 20.0 #for rastering images
    minimum_time_interval: 0.5
    transform_timeout: 0.2
    tf_buffer_duration: 30.
    stack_size_to_use: 40000000 #// program needs a larger stack size to serialize large maps
    enable_interactive_mode: true

    # General Parameters
    use_scan_matching: true
    use_scan_barycenter: true
    minimum_travel_distance: 0.5
    minimum_travel_heading: 0.5
    scan_buffer_size: 10
    scan_buffer_maximum_scan_distance: 10.0
    link_match_minimum_response_fine: 0.1  
    link_scan_maximum_distance: 1.5
    loop_search_maximum_distance: 3.0
    do_loop_closing: true 
    loop_match_minimum_chain_size: 10           
    loop_match_maximum_variance_coarse: 3.0  
    loop_match_minimum_response_coarse: 0.35    
    loop_match_minimum_response_fine: 0.45

    # Correlation Parameters - Correlation Parameters
    correlation_search_space_dimension: 0.5
    correlation_search_space_resolution: 0.01
    correlation_search_space_smear_deviation: 0.1 

    # Correlation Parameters - Loop Closure Parameters
    loop_search_space_dimension: 8.0
    loop_search_space_resolution: 0.05
    loop_search_space_smear_deviation: 0.03

    # Scan Matcher Parameters
    distance_variance_penalty: 0.5      
    angle_variance_penalty: 1.0    

    fine_search_angle_offset: 0.00349     
    coarse_search_angle_offset: 0.349   
    coarse_angle_resolution: 0.0349        
    minimum_angle_penalty: 0.9
    minimum_distance_penalty: 0.5
    use_response_expansion: true`


Expected behavior
The second turtlebot should be able to do localization and have an in tact tf tree such as the one in this image:

Actual behavior
The tf tree looks likes this sometimes:

Or like this:

Also I get these errors:
[planner_server-7] [INFO] [1720721131.734336613] [tb1.global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available, tf error: Could not find a connection between 'map' and 'base_link' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.
and
[amcl-1] [INFO] [1720721132.919562224] [tb1.amcl]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_scan' at time 1703.870 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
Additional information
What confuses me is why there is a transform from map to base_link. I thought amcl calculates a tf from map to odom, so my question is where is that transform coming from? And why is it so inconsistent (i.e., why does it sometimes work?)?

Is it possible both robots publish into the same  tf and tf_static topic with the same frame names?
